# Python: How to get image from USB Webcam?

Tags: python, opencv, camera, usb, video-capture

I am very new in programming with python :)

My Setup:

Windows 11 Pro

Python 3.7

OpenCV 4.7

Webcam: HD Pro Webcam C920 from logitech

I want to access the camera image in Python. Everything works with my integrated camera.
When I want to access the USB camera, nothing works. I do not get video from my USB webcam.

I try the following code to see, if there is a camera.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

print(cap.isOpened())
```

It works with my integrated Webcam. I get a `True`

With `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)` i get `False`

But if i try this with `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)` i get nothing back and there is no error. The program just keeps running. My conclusion: Somehow the USB camera has to work. Otherwise I would also expect a False for `cap = VideoCapture(1)`.

I have already found and tried many things on the Internet. Unfortunately, nothing has helped.
I have also tried pygame, but that does not seem to run under windows.

How do I get video from my USB camera?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: when you do `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)` and then you do `print(cap.isOpened())`  what do you get as result?

Comment: Ahhhh, I got it.

I'm getting a ´True´ back there.

Comment: I don't know why, but I have to wait for 30 seconds before I can use it. Strange. Do you know why it takes so long until the image from the USB cam opens? This is much faster with the integrated webcam